# Should you use related variables in your code?

Tags: oop, variables, naming-conventions, naming

Lately I was wondering if it is a bad practice to use variables in your code that are related to each other (e.g. a = 2 * b). A concrete example would be euro and dollars. Let's say we have a Person class who has some balance in euros and dollars (coded in java for demonstration):

```
class Person {

    float balanceInEuros;
    float balanceInDollars;

    public Person(...) { // Problem 1 (see down below)

    }
}
```

Problem 1: What do you need to put in the constructor arguments? Both variables are `float` so we can't differentiate between to distinct constructors (java can have multiple constructors for a class, as long as they have a different type of arguments). To solve this we can make two separate methods to return a Person, for example:

```
public static createPersonWithEuros(float euros) {
    Person person = new Person();
    person.setEuros(euros);
    return person;
}
// Similar for dollars...
```

Problem 2: Now we have no value for the dollars, so a method `person.getDollars()` would result in an error. Of course this can be fixed again by adding a single line in the `createPersonWithEuros()` method: `person.setDollars(Person.EXCHANGE_RATE_EURO_DOLLAR * euros)` or something along those lines.

---

### Arguments for

- It feels more natural to use dollars and euros instead of a so called 'balance' which has no concrete meaning.
- It makes more sense and thus enhances the readability of the code

### Arguments against

- By using a universal 'balance' with functions to calculate to euros/dollars etc., it results in cleaner code (less functions/bulk code...)
- You need more memory to store essentially the same thing, which could be bad

What is better and why?

EDIT: Another thing I am concerned with is that I programmed this particular example in an OO language. What if this was written in javascript for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By creating a separate class `Balance` which has an amount and a currency, you can use a single constructor with a 'balance' parameter and use euros, dollars, pounds and so on as you like. All conversion goes to the `Balance` class and `Person` can use balances regardless of currencies, conversion rates and so on.

Comment: I'll wait a day or two to accept this as an answer. Maybe others will come up with a different answer